# Get the last element of a window in Spark 2.1.1

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I have a dataframe in which I have subcategories, and  want the last element of each of these subcategories.

```
val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("name").orderBy("count")
sqlContext
    .createDataFrame(
      Seq[(String, Int)](
        ("A", 1),
        ("A", 2),
        ("A", 3),
        ("B", 10),
        ("B", 20),
        ("B", 30)
      ))
    .toDF("name", "count")
    .withColumn("firstCountOfName", first("count").over(windowSpec))
    .withColumn("lastCountOfName", last("count").over(windowSpec))
    .show()
```

returns me something strange:

```
+----+-----+----------------+---------------+                                   
|name|count|firstCountOfName|lastCountOfName|
+----+-----+----------------+---------------+
|   B|   10|              10|             10|
|   B|   20|              10|             20|
|   B|   30|              10|             30|
|   A|    1|               1|              1|
|   A|    2|               1|              2|
|   A|    3|               1|              3|
+----+-----+----------------+---------------+
```

As we can see, the `first` value returned is correctly computed, but the `last` isn't, it's always the current value of the column.

Has someone a solution to do what I want?

Comment: isn't "orderBy" + "first/last" on the same column the same as "min"/"max"

Comment: Could be; but I have the same behavior with max anyway.

Comment: The difference is that using `max` doesn't need the orderBy, then when you define your windowSpec using only partitionBy it works.

Comment: Hmm, removing the orderBy and using max seems to work in my simplified case above. But, In my real case, I can't do that, because the data which I want the last value isn't a number.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the issue [SPARK-20969](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20969), you should be able to get the expected results by defining adequate bounds to your window, as shown below.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val windowSpec = Window
  .partitionBy("name")
  .orderBy("count")
  .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)

sqlContext
  .createDataFrame(
    Seq[(String, Int)](
      ("A", 1),
      ("A", 2),
      ("A", 3),
      ("B", 10),
      ("B", 20),
      ("B", 30)
    ))
  .toDF("name", "count")
  .withColumn("firstCountOfName", first("count").over(windowSpec))
  .withColumn("lastCountOfName", last("count").over(windowSpec))
  .show()
```

Alternatively, if your are ordering on the same column you are computing first and last, you can change for `min` and `max` with a non-ordered window, then it should also work properly.